# Apache - rewrite rule for user folders

Tags: apache

I'm trying to get a url like www.domain.com/user/myuser to forward to www.domain.com/user/index.html?user=myuser the code below does not work.

```
RewriteRule ^user/?$ /user/index.html?user=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`does not work.` is not helpful.

In this case your regex seems to be wrong. `^user/?$` means starts with user has an optional slash as the last letter

what you mean is

`^user/(.*)$` which means match user/anything and redirect to /user/index.html?user=anything

so 
`RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/index.html?user=$1 [QSA,L]`

should work